# Unable to retrieve BLE RSSI value using cordova/phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, bluetooth-lowenergy, cordova-plugins

I'm using Cordova/Phonegap plugin [Ble Central](https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central#readrssi) to connect to BLE devices using Android Phone.

As per the documentation on github code is :

```
onConnect = function(device) {
        ble.isConnected(deviceId,
                function() {
                    console.log("Connected");
                },
                function() {
                    console.error("Disconnected");
                }
        );               
        ble.readRSSI(deviceId, function(rssi) {
                console.log('read RSSI',rssi,'with device', deviceId);
        });            
};

ble.connect(deviceId, onConnect, app.onError);
```

Even though ble.isConnected() fucntion returns true, RSSI value never returns.

What could be the issue here ?? Has anyone tried using [cordova-plugin-ble-central](https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central) to retrieve RSSI ?

Answer (score 0):

Try retrieving rssi from Peripheral data.

```
onConnect = function(device) {
        console.log('rssi' + device.rssi);      
};
```

See if it gives a proper value.